# Who are these historical people alluded to by R.A. Lafferty?

Tags: short-stories, allusions, r-a-lafferty

In "The Six Fingers of Time", by R. A. Lafferty, available for free [here](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/31663) on Project Gutenberg, there is a claim that having an extra finger or toe is associated with genius. The text gives some evidence for this claim:

> Yet there were hints here of a Corsican who commonly kept a hand hidden, of an earlier and more bizarre commander who wore always a mailed glove, of another man with a glove between the two, hints that the multiplex-adept, Leonardo himself, who sometimes drew the hands of men and often those of monsters with six fingers, may himself have had the touch.

The Corsican is undoubtedly Napoleon Bonaparte. The last one is Leonardo da Vinci, in whose painting *The Last Supper* one of the apostles did have [six fingers on one hand](http://e-arthistory5.blogspot.com/2018/03/leonardos-last-supper.html) (introduced when the painting was restored and later fixed). Who are the other two?

Comment: Might be in Wikipedia's category; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:People_with_polydactyly

Comment: These aren't actually six-fingered people; they're just people for which a case might be made that they had six fingers (e.g., maybe because they always wore a glove on one hand). Possibly I should put "evidence" in quotes to make that clearer.